# Group by with 3 columns

Tags: php

I have 3 columns to get data.

1- amount, 2- transaction_id and order_id

Made group by (transaction_id),  sum(amount) and get all order_id.

```
id  order_id    transaction_id   amount
1   1           3333             698.00
1   2           3333             758.00
1   3           3333             560.00
1   4           3333             360.00
1   5           5555             225.00
1   6           5555             102.00
1   7           2222              36.00
```

See image
[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UBMy.png)

`SELECT sum(amount) as sum, transaction_id, order_id FROM table WHERE ID='1' GROUP BY transaction_id`

Got back:
The sum is OK.
The transaction id is OK.
The order id got back just the first of each transaction id.

I what to see order id like this transaction id 3333 - order id 1,2,3,4

Tried `explode()` but did not work

Help needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the db is mysql (please tag your db in the question), use [group_concat](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) for this like:

`SELECT sum(amouNt) as sum, transaction_id, group_concat(order_id) orders FROM table WHERE ID='1' GROUP BY transaction_id`

This will return `orders` column with comma separated values like 1,2,3,4

Comment: Thanks, GAGANSHERA!!!!  First time using stack and response was fast thanks again!!!!

Comment: @jmart glad to help you. If the answer worked for you, please mark it as correct :)

Comment: You'll see a tick mark icon below the upvote/downvote buttons. That's the mark as accepted button.